# Mootools pagination with AJAX and Moustache template

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination, mootools

I'm trying to display the list of Products using mustache templates, bootstrap styles and [mootools pagination plugin](http://mootools.net/forge/p/xpagination).

When debugging in Mozilla I don't have any errors or warnings about my code, but Products simply not displaying, also despite the fact that server return some in response.

This is my page for now:

```
<div class="container">
        <div id="container-left">
            <h4>Left</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="container-active"></div>
        <div id="container-right">
            <h4>Right</h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/MooTools-Core-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/MooTools-More-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/xPagination.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/xPagination.JSON.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/mustachejs/0.8.2/mustache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/xPagination.JSON.mustache.js"></script>

    <script id="products-template" type="text/mustache-template">
<ul class="list-group">
{{#.}}
  <li class="list-group-item">
        <label for="{{name}}">Name: </label> {{name}}
</br>
        <label for="{{price}}">Price:  </label> {{price}}
</br>
<a href="product/view?id={{id}}">Full description</a>
  </li>
{{/.}}
</ul>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'json',
            url : 'product/upload_products',
            success : function(data) {
                var mustache = $('#products-template').html();
                var options = {
                    records_per_page : 5,
                    template : mustache
                };
                var pagination = new xPagination.JSON.mustache(
                        $('container-left'), $('container-active'),
                        $('container-right'), data, options);
            }
        })
    </script>
```

What mistakes did I do ?

Comment: Hi Mark, I saw your post in the Forge. You are using both jQuery `$.ajax({` and MooTools `$('container-left')` with the `$` variable. Can you use MooTools to everything instead? or use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: @Sergio could you be more descriptive ? I tried to replace all `$` with `jQuery` - nothing happend, then tried replace `$` with `MooTools`, but getting the error wich tells that no such function is present. Would you produce the code sample that may resolve my problem ?

Comment: DO you have this online so we can take a look?

Comment: @Sergio this project is running only on my local machine. source code available on my github, but i didn't push this not working snippet to it

Comment: I don't actually see you loading jQuery in the code you posted so you could replace that jQUery AJAX with MooTools Request.JSON (http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Request/Request.JSON). Try that and  [edit] the question if you have a problem with the implementation.